# Select form filter using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select, filter

I've created a page for the list of available jobs.
There are two features in the page a Pager and Select form filter. 
I need some help how the Select form filter works. 
Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image]

This page is powered by wordpress, each job post created via Post type. See my code below:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'job',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true);

    $job = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select class="filterby">
        <option>Search Location</option>
        <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
        <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
        <option value="South-Perth">South Perth</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="inline-block vertical-middle s-btn"> 
    <input type="submit"   value="Search" name="search">
</div>    

<?php while ($job->have_posts()) : $job->the_post();?>
    <section id="content-area" class="job clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            Job Details here
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endwhile;?>

<div class="paging">
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
            'next_text'    => __('Next'),
            'total' => $job->max_num_pages);
        echo paginate_links( $args );  
    ?>
</div>
```

I hope you can help to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle to filter with the event `change()` of the select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter').change(function(){
    $('.filterable').each(function(){
      if($(this).data('ref') != $('.filter').val() && $('.filter').val() != -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select class="filter">
    <option value="-1">No selection</option>
    <option value="1">City 1</option>
    <option value="2">City 2</option>
    <option value="3">City 3</option>
    <option value="4">City 4</option>
  </select>  
</form>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="1">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 1</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="2">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 2</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="3">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 3</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="3">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 3</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="2">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 2</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="2">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 2</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="4">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 4</p>
</div>

<div class="filterable" data-ref="4">
  <p>This is a dummy div for city 4</p>
</div>
```

Anyway this example only works for single selection, not multiple selection. The method when the `selected` option changes, check the `data-ref` attribute of every div and shows/hides the div by looking at the condition

Comment: Also do you know how the filters works using PHP or wordpress function? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh ok :)
BTW, I like the filter works after i click the submit button, I tried this one and it's not work properly. I add an id="filter-job" on the input button.

`$(document).ready(function() {   
      $( '#filter-job' ).click(function() {   
      $('.filter').change(function(){   
        $('.filterable').each(function(){    
           if($(this).data('ref') != $('.filter').val() && $('.filter').val() != -1) {    
            $(this).hide();   
            } else {   
            $(this).show();   
            }   
        });     
      });   
      });   
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.change()` jquery method as it works into the example here
https://api.jquery.com/change/
(watch the demo).

- Then try something like `$("a").attr("href", valueVariable);`
- attr also can be used as `$("element").attr("id", valueVariable);`
- valueVariable have the id of an element in the page.

### **Tip**

On normal HTML when you use something like:

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

This goes to the id element into the same page.

*Comment the results and vote please.*